# I'm trying to add a count to the number of searches found in my code

Tags: excel, vba, counter, worksheet

My code follows:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ExitLoop As Boolean
Dim SearchString As String, FoundAt As String


Set ws = Worksheets("detail_report")


On Error GoTo Err


Set oRange = ws.Cells

SearchString = "front input"

Set aCell = oRange.Find(What:=SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
    Set bCell = aCell
    FoundAt = aCell.Address
    Do While ExitLoop = False
        Set aCell = oRange.FindNext(After:=aCell)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
            FoundAt = FoundAt & ", " & aCell.Address
        Else
            ExitLoop = True
        End If
    Loop
Else
    MsgBox SearchString & " not Found"
End If

MsgBox "The Search String has been found these locations: " & FoundAt
Exit Sub
Err:
MsgBox Err.Description


End Sub
```

I added the below code but don't know how to add the counter part:

```
Dim S As String
Dim count As Integer
```

Comment: This isn't very clear - could you explain what you want a counter for, and how you expect it to work?

Comment: count how how times the word in SearchString  is found in the excel worksheet @Grade'Eh'Bacon

Comment: I think it would help if you explained (in words, not in VBA code) what you are trying to accomplish with your program. Right now, I can't actually tell what's happening with it, and the way you have laid out the structure starting with "If Not acell"... is confusing to me. As it stands, I don't expect this to hit more than 1 match before closing [though I may be misinterpreting on a quick read], so it seems that it isn't doing what you expect.

Comment: I honestly don't understand the 3 DVs. The question and problem are pretty clearly defined. @Grade'Eh'Bacon - the `If Not aCell Is Nothing Then` is simply saying if the SearchString is found the first time (at `Set aCell = ...`, then continue the process.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman It's not that particular expression I find confusing, it's the method of the Do While loop, and the lack of explanation as to what the counter is used for - shouldnt have to make even educated guesses about these things...

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon - I will admit the method used is a bit clunkier than what I have seen/used to perform similar functions. :) I just re-read your comment, and see where I missed your point :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current code you have you don't even need to use a counter. Instead you can load `FoundAt` into an array and then use the `Ubound` to get the total count. *Note you have to add 1 since the array is 0 based.*

Add these lines before your final `Msgbox`

```
Dim iCount() as String
iCount = Split(FoundAt,", ")

MsgBox "The Search String has been found " & UBound(iCount)+1 & " times at these locations: " & FoundAt
```