# What i can't figure out is how to display the searched word and number of times its shows up on a different worksheet on excel

Tags: vba, excel, loops

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim oRange As Range, aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ExitLoop As Boolean
    Dim SearchString As String, FoundAt As String
    Dim iCount() As String




 iCount = Split(FoundAt, ", ")



    Set ws = Worksheets("detail_report")


    On Error GoTo Err


    Set oRange = ws.Cells

    SearchString = "leak"

    Set aCell = oRange.Find(What:=SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        Set bCell = aCell
        FoundAt = aCell.Address
        Do While ExitLoop = False
            Set aCell = oRange.FindNext(After:=aCell)

            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
                FoundAt = FoundAt & ", " & aCell.Address
            Else
                ExitLoop = True
            End If
        Loop

         iCount = Split(FoundAt, ", ")

        MsgBox "The Search String has been found " & UBound(iCount) + 1 & " times at these locations:"

    Else
        MsgBox SearchString & " not Found"
    End If

    MsgBox "The Search String has been found in these locations: " & FoundAt
    Exit Sub
Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description


End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Dele. Take a look at  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to best format your question. Your title is a little long. What do you think is wrong with your code?

Comment: What is your error message or the problem with current code? Please share your expected and actual outputs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I'm trying to add a count to the number of searches found in my code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178704/im-trying-to-add-a-count-to-the-number-of-searches-found-in-my-code)

Comment: This is a duplicate of your own question from yesterday - and you accepted an answer there. You would get better results if you narrowed down your original question by commenting on the answer which was provided.

Comment: Different question from that. Currently practicing and need some insights  @Grade'Eh'Bacon

Comment: Apologies - in the future, you may find help more quickly if you show only the relevant code to your question. So in this case, you could really ignore everything leading up to the msgbox, because the question is simply "How do I display text on a particular cell of a different sheet".

Comment: That simplifies it thanks, so i tried doing that and adding @micstr code but i'm getting a subscript out of range error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your code is showing up as a `Msgbox`. It is not clear what you are asking but if you need to put the results into another sheet then you could add this to your code.

Instead of:

```
MsgBox "The Search String has been found " & UBound(iCount) + 1 & " times at these locations:"
```

You could set an output worksheet and write the values. Create a sheet called output or name it whatever.

```
 Dim outws as worksheet
 Set outws = Worksheets("output") 


 # You can set more sophisticated routine here like going to last empty row
 # Lots of stack overflow code for that if you search

 # Simple paste in A1 the string and B1 the count
 # I am showing you two ways to reference cells  
 outws.Range("A1").Value = SearchString  
 outws.Sheets(outws).Range(Cells(1,2)).Value =  UBound(iCount) + 1
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm getting a subscript out of range
Set outws = Worksheets("output") @micstr

Comment: @DeleAwe - did you create a worksheet called output as micstr suggested in his answer? Either that or change the sheet name reference in the code to whatever sheet you wish to put that output on.

Comment: Yes i figured out the subscript problem but now its giving me a type mismatch @ScottHoltzman

Comment: @DeleAwe - change `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(outws).` to just `outws`

Comment: Thanks Scott - been jumping between languages this week

Comment: Tried it still not working. no error just gives the cell number "leak" is located in @ScottHoltzman

Comment: Got it Thanks for your help everybody

Comment: Dele - you have your counter set as a string (which means characters) and not as Long or Integer (number format) i.e. DIM iCount as Long. Please also edit your answer to be clear on what you wanted as the moderators have suggested. Add some text ahead of your code.